# Appending the ColumnTransformer() result to the original data within a pipeline?

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

This is my input data:

[image]

This is the desired output with transformations applied to the columns r, f, and m and the result is appended to the original data

[image]

Here's the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer    

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10, 3)), columns=list('rfm'))
column_trans = ColumnTransformer(
    [('r_std', StandardScaler(), ['r']),
     ('f_std', StandardScaler(), ['f']),
     ('m_std', StandardScaler(), ['m']),
     ('r_boxcox', PowerTransformer(method='box-cox'), ['r']),
     ('f_boxcox', PowerTransformer(method='box-cox'), ['f']),
     ('m_boxcox', PowerTransformer(method='box-cox'), ['m']),
    ])

transformed = column_trans.fit_transform(df)
new_cols = ['r_std', 'f_std', 'm_std', 'r_boxcox', 'f_boxcox', 'm_boxcox']

transformed_df = pd.DataFrame(transformed, columns=new_cols)
pd.concat([df, transformed_df], axis = 1)
```

I'll need additional transformers as well, so I need to keep the originating columns within a pipeline. Is there a better way to handle this? In particular doing the concatenation and column naming within a pipeline?

Answer (score 9):

One way to do it would be using a *dummy transformer* that just returns the transformed column with its original value:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import PowerTransformer    

np.random.seed(1714)

class NoTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        assert isinstance(X, pd.DataFrame)
        return X
```

I'm adding an *id* column to the dataset so I can show the use of the *remainder* parameter in `ColumnTransformer()`, which I find very useful.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((np.arange(10).reshape((10, 1)),
                             np.random.randint(1,100,size=(10, 3)))),
                  columns=["id"] + list('rfm'))
```

Using *remainder* with the value *passthrough* (by default the value is *drop*) one can retain the columns that are not transformed; from the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html).

And using the `NoTransformer()` dummy class we can transform the columns 'r', 'f', 'm' to have the same value.

```
column_trans = ColumnTransformer(
    [('r_original', NoTransformer(), ['r']),
     ('f_original', NoTransformer(), ['f']),
     ('m_original', NoTransformer(), ['m']),
     ('r_std', StandardScaler(), ['r']),
     ('f_std', StandardScaler(), ['f']),
     ('m_std', StandardScaler(), ['m']),
     ('r_boxcox', PowerTransformer(method='box-cox'), ['r']),
     ('f_boxcox', PowerTransformer(method='box-cox'), ['f']),
     ('m_boxcox', PowerTransformer(method='box-cox'), ['m']),
    ], remainder="passthrough")
```

A tip if you want to transform many more columns: the fitted `ColumnTransformer()` class (*column_trans* in your case) has a *transformers_* method that lets you access the names `['r_std', 'f_std', 'm_std', 'r_boxcox', 'f_boxcox', 'm_boxcox']` programmatically:

```
column_trans.transformers_

#[('r_original', NoTransformer(), ['r']),
# ('f_original', NoTransformer(), ['f']),
# ('m_original', NoTransformer(), ['m']),
# ('r_std', StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True), ['r']),
# ('f_std', StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True), ['f']),
# ('m_std', StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True), ['m']),
# ('r_boxcox',
#  PowerTransformer(copy=True, method='box-cox', standardize=True),
#  ['r']),
# ('f_boxcox',
#  PowerTransformer(copy=True, method='box-cox', standardize=True),
#  ['f']),
# ('m_boxcox',
#  PowerTransformer(copy=True, method='box-cox', standardize=True),
#  ['m']),
# ('remainder', 'passthrough', [0])]
```

Finally, I think your code could be simplified like this:

```
column_trans_2 = ColumnTransformer(
    ([
     ('original', NoTransformer(), ['r', 'f', 'm']),
     ('std', StandardScaler(), ['r', 'f', 'm']),
     ('boxcox', PowerTransformer(method='box-cox'), ['r', 'f', 'm']),
    ]), remainder="passthrough")

transformed_2 = column_trans_2.fit_transform(df)
column_trans_2.transformers_

#[('std',
#  StandardScaler(copy=True, with_mean=True, with_std=True),
#  ['r', 'f', 'm']),
# ('boxcox',
#  PowerTransformer(copy=True, method='box-cox', standardize=True),
#  ['r', 'f', 'm'])]
```

And assign the column names programmatically through *transformers_*:

```
new_col_names = []
for i in range(len(column_trans_2.transformers)):
    new_col_names += [column_trans_2.transformers[i][0] + '_' + s for s in column_trans_2.transformers[i][2]]
# The non-transformed columns ('id' in this case) will be appended on the right of
# the array and do not show up in the 'transformers_' method.
# Add the id columns to the col_names manually
new_col_names += ['id']

# ['original_r', 'original_f', 'original_m', 'std_r', 'std_f', 'std_m', 'boxcox_r',
#  'boxcox_f', 'boxcox_m', 'id']


pd.DataFrame(transformed_2, columns=new_col_names)
```

Answer (score 4):

Yes, there is a way to do this which luckily is included in SKLearn. In the original documentation of [ColumnTransformer](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html) you can find a confusing but useful line, which is the following:

> transformer{‘drop’, ‘passthrough’} or estimator
>
> Estimator must support fit and transform. Special-cased strings ‘drop’ and ‘passthrough’ are accepted as well, to indicate to drop the columns or to pass them through untransformed, respectively.

This means that if you want to keep a column during `ColumnTransformer` or drop a column during `ColumnTransformer`, you can simply indicate it using one of the two special-cased strings, just like this:

```
column_trans = ColumnTransformer(
[('r_std', StandardScaler(), ['r']),
 ('f_std', StandardScaler(), ['f']),
 ('m_std', StandardScaler(), ['m']),
 ('r_boxcox', PowerTransformer(method='box-cox'), ['r']),
 ('f_boxcox', PowerTransformer(method='box-cox'), ['f']),
 ('m_boxcox', PowerTransformer(method='box-cox'), ['m']),
 ('col_keep', 'passthrough', ['r','f','m'])
])
```

If you then use the `ColumnTransformer`, those 3 columns will be kept and not dropped. Alternatively, if you use `'drop'` instead of `'passthrough'`, you can selectively drop certain columns. This in combination with `remainder='passthrough'` would allow you to drop some columns and keep all of the others. I hope you find this useful!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`FeatureUnion`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.pipeline.FeatureUnion.html) together with identity transformer:

```py
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
from sklearn.preprocessing import FunctionTransformer

def identity(X):
    return X

identity_transformer = FunctionTransformer(identity)

column_trans = FeatureUnion([
    ('original', identity_transformer),
    ('extra', ColumnTransformer(...))
])
```